# Why does this code for a list fail for large entries?

Tags: python

I am writing a code for a cipher and I want to turn one-digit numbers to two-digit numbers with 0 at the front of them.

I want to turn a list like this:

```
[":","2",":","3",":","4",":"]
```

to this:

```
[":", "0","2", ":", "0","3". ":", "0","4",":"]
```

But I don't get why my code fails when the list gets large.
Here's my code:

```
text = str(input("Enter the text you want to encode: "))
text = ':' + text + ':'

n = len(text)
text = list(text)
t_test = text

for i in range(2,n):
    if text[i] == ':' and text[i-2] == ":":
        t_test.insert((i-1),"0")
t_test = text
print(text)
```

for example when I input this:

```
1:2:3:4:5:6
```

it fails to insert a zero in front of the 5 and 6. It outputs this:

```
[':', '0', '1', ':', '0', '2', ':', '0', '3', ':', '0', '4', ':', '5', ':', '6', ':']
```

instead of:

```
[':', '0', '1', ':', '0', '2', ':', '0', '3', ':', '0', '4', ':', '0', '5', ':', '0', '6', ':']
```

I have tried for smaller entries and it works, but I don't know why it starts to fail at some point.

Comment: You are looping over a range that goes to the *original* end of the list.  As you insert items into the list, it gets longer, and items at the end get pushed to an index that's no longer in your range.

Comment: @jasonharper is there a way to fix it?

Comment: General Rule: don't modify the item you are iterating over.

Comment: @MarkTolonen but I am modifying a different variable t_test not test.

Comment: When you assign `t_test = text` you make `t_test` a *reference* to `text`, not a copy of it.

Comment: Oh I see I didn’t know that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to modify a string it might be better to stick with string functions. For example, you could use regex to find single digits and add a leading zero:

```
import re

text = '2:3:4:5:6:10:44'

t_test = re.sub(r'\b(\d)\b', r'0\1', ':' + text + ':')
print(t_test, list(t_test), sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
:02:03:04:05:06:10:44:
[':', '0', '2', ':', '0', '3', ':', '0', '4', ':', '0', '5', ':', '0', '6', ':', '1', '0', ':', '4', '4', ':']
```

Comment: Wouldn't `re.sub(r'\b(\d)\b', r'0\1', f':{text}:')` be better?

Comment: @AnnZen OP didn't specify Python 3 so they may not have access to f-strings

Answer (score 0):

Another way, just in case you don't want to use regular expressions. Here we use (basically) only methods of the `str` class and a list comprehension.

```
text = '1:2:3:4:5:6'
list_ = text.split(':')
format_number = lambda x: f'0{x}' if x.isdigit() and len(x) == 1 else x
result = [* ':' + ":".join([format_number(str(x)) for x in list_]) + ':']
```

output for `print(result)`:

```
[':', '0', '1', ':', '0', '2', ':', '0', '3', ':', '0', '4', ':', '0', '5', ':', '0', '6', ':']
```

Answer (score 0):

For one, the code you posted doesn't work for any entry, big or small. Here is how I used a list comprehension to convert a list like your example showed:

```
l = [":","2",":","3",":","4",":"]
l = [a for b in [["0",i] if i.isdigit() else [i] for i in l] for a in b]
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[':', '0', '2', ':', '0', '3', ':', '0', '4', ':']
```

---

Here's another way:

```
l = [":","2",":","3",":","4",":"]
l = ' '.join([f"0 {i}" if i.isdigit() else i for i in l]).split()
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[':', '0', '2', ':', '0', '3', ':', '0', '4', ':']
```